# Steps of Permutation

Tags: code-golf, math, permutations

Write a function which takes a set of integers and prints every permutation of the set, and the swap performed in between each step

#### Input

a set of integers, for example (0, 1, 2)

#### Output

the list of permutations and swaps in the format
(set)
(swap)
(set)
...

#### Test case

```
Input: 
(3, 1, 5)

Output:
(3, 1, 5)
(3, 1)
(1, 3, 5)
(3, 5)
(1, 5, 3)
(1, 3)
(3, 5, 1)
(3, 5)
(5, 3, 1)
(3, 1)
(5, 1, 3)
```

#### Rules

- You can format the set of numbers however you want.
- You can do the swaps in any order
- You can repeat permutations and swaps in order to get a new one
- Your code doesn't have to actually perform the swaps, the output just needs to show what swap was made between your last output and your current one
- Your code only needs to function for sets with 2 or more elements
- The set you're given will have no repeating elements (e.g. (0, 1, 1, 2) is invalid)

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: Can we use randomness?

Comment: You mean just do a load of random swaps until you happen to achieve all permutations? Yes, but you have to be sure that all permutations have been printed

Comment: @Rod yes, I specified that this is allowed in the rules.

Comment: @Rod, oh sorry, no repeating elements. I'll edit to specify thanks

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first challenge. I would suggest editing the example so the elements don't get confused with the indices, like use set `(3, 1, 4)` or so -- reading it the first time I was very confused because the first swap `0,1` swapped the elements `0,1` but also the indices `0,1`, but then the next swap didn't follow that pattern. I'll also point you to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/42963) where you can post challenges and get feedback before posting them to the main site.

Comment: @TimmyD thanks for the suggestion, I have changed the example. I saw the link to the sandbox just after I posted this, I'll post there first from now on!

Comment: Hi, reading again the puzzle (after answering it :P) I am a bit confused about `You can repeat permutations and swaps in order to get a **new one**`. So, are there any invalid permutations?

Comment: The [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) generates the minimum necessary sequence.

Comment: @Master_ex I didn't really mean anything by "a new one", sorry if it was confusing

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>449</s> 426 bytes

```
import java.util.*;interface P{static Set s=new HashSet();static void main(String[]a){o(Arrays.toString(a));while(s.size()<n(a.length)){p(a);o(Arrays.toString(a));}}static<T>void o(T z){System.out.println(z);s.add(z);}static int n(int x){return x==1?1:x*n(x-1);}static void p(String[]a){Random r=new Random();int l=a.length,j=r.nextInt(l),i=r.nextInt(l);String t=a[j];a[j]=a[i];a[i]=t;System.out.println("("+a[j]+","+t+")");}}
```

Brute force approach. It keeps making random swaps until all the possible permutations have took place. It uses a Set of the string representation of the array in order to check how many different states have been generated. For n different integers there are n! = 1*2*3*..*n distinct permutations.

**Update**

- Followed Kevin Cruijssen's suggestions to golf it a bit more.

Ungolfed:

```
import java.util.*;

interface P {

    static Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();

    static void main(String[] a) {
        // prints the original input
        o(Arrays.toString(a));
        while (s.size() < n(a.length)) {
            p(a);
            // prints the array after the swap
            o(Arrays.toString(a));
        }
    }

    static void o(String z) {
        System.out.println(z);
        // adds the string representation of the array to the HashSet
        s.add(z);
    }

    // method that calculates n!
    static int n(int x) {
        if (x == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return x * n(x - 1);
    }

    // makes a random swap and prints what the swap is
    static void p(String[] a) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int l = a.length, j = r.nextInt(l), i = r.nextInt(l);
        String t = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
        System.out.println("(" + a[j] + "," + t + ")");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$ javac P.java
$ java P 1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
(2,1)
[2, 1, 3]
(1,1)
[2, 1, 3]
(2,2)
[2, 1, 3]
(3,1)
[2, 3, 1]
(3,1)
[2, 1, 3]
(1,2)
[1, 2, 3]
(1,1)
[1, 2, 3]
(3,2)
[1, 3, 2]
(2,3)
[1, 2, 3]
(3,1)
[3, 2, 1]
(3,1)
[1, 2, 3]
(3,3)
[1, 2, 3]
(1,2)
[2, 1, 3]
(1,3)
[2, 3, 1]
(1,2)
[1, 3, 2]
(3,1)
[3, 1, 2]
```

As you can see there are many more swaps than the necessary minimum. But it seems to work :-D

As a bonus, it works with strings too, i.e.

```
$ java P 'one' 'two'
[one, two]
(two,one)
[two, one]
```

Comment: do you have an un-golfed version for us to take a look at your method using?

Comment: @Billyoyo: Added the un-golfed code. Nothing fancy there however :-)

Comment: You can golf it a bit. No need to fix warnings, so you can removed the Set declarations: `Set s=new HashSet();`. Your code in the method `n` can be a single return: `static int n(int x){return x==1?1:x*n(x-1);}`. And you can replace `String z` in your method `o` with a generic instead: `static<T>void o(T z){System.out.println(z);s.add(z);}`. All combined it would get down to **426 bytes**.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 102 bytes

```
<<Combinatorica`
Riffle[#,BlockMap[Pick[#[[1]],#!=0&/@({1,-1}.#)]&,#,2,1]]&@*MinimumChangePermutations
```

**Examples**

*//Column for a clearer result*

```
%[{1,3,5}]//Column
(*
{1,3,5}
{1,3}
{3,1,5}
{3,5}
{5,1,3}
{5,1}
{1,5,3}
{1,3}
{3,5,1}
{3,5}
{5,3,1}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 186 bytes

```js
f=
a=>{console.log(a);d=a.slice().fill(-1);s=[...d.keys()];for(i=l=a.length;i;)s[k=(j=s.indexOf(--i))+d[i]]<i?(console.log(a[s[j]=s[k]],a[s[k]=i]),console.log(s.map(n=>a[n])),i=l):d[i]*=-1}
;
```

```html
<input id=i><input type=button value=Go! onclick=f(i.value.split`,`)>
```

Note: I'm not sure how flexible the output format is, may be I could do this for 171 bytes:

```
a=>{console.log(a);d=a.slice().fill(-1);s=[...d.keys()];for(i=l=a.length;i;)s[k=(j=s.indexOf(--i))+d[i]]<i?console.log(a[s[j]=s[k]],a[s[k]=i],s.map(n=>a[n],i=l)):d[i]*=-1}
```

Works by performing the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) algorithm on the shuffle array of indices and translating back to the input array. Ungolfed:

```
function steps(array) {
    console.log(array); // initial row
    var d = a.slice().fill(-1); // direction values
    var s = [...a.keys()]; // initial (identity) shuffle
    var l = a.length;
    for (var i = l; i; ) { // start by trying to move the last element
        var j = s.indexOf(--i);
        var k = j + d[i]; // proposed exchange
        if (s[k] < i) { // only exchange with lower index (within bounds)
            console.log(a[s[k]],a[i]); // show values being exchanged
            s[j] = s[k];
            s[k] = i; // do the exchange on the shuffle
            console.log(s.map(n=>a[n])); // show the shuffled array
            i = l; // start from the last element again
        } else {
            d[i] *= -1; // next time, try moving it the other way
        } // --i above causes previous element to be tried
    } // until no movable elements can be found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 86 bytes

```
puts (2..(a=gets.scan(/\d+/).uniq).size).map{|i|a.permutation(i).map{|e|?(+e*", "+?)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 135 bytes

```
p=permutations;f=filter
q(a:b:xs)=(\x->f(uncurry(/=)).zip x)a b:q(b:xs);q _=[]
l=head.f(all((==2).length).q).p.p
f=zip.l<*>map head.q.l
```

output:

```
> f [3,1,5]
[([3,1,5],(3,1)),([1,3,5],(3,5)),([1,5,3],(1,5)),([5,1,3],(1,3)),([5,3,1],(5,3))]
```

I am using the standard `permutations` function, which is not based on swaps, so I am taking the permutations of the permutations and finding one that happens to be a chain of swaps.